# Assigning one value for all string MyStr elements

Tags: c#, arrays, string, assign

```
string[] MyStr = new string[100];
```

This is probably simplest thing ever, so shame to ask, but.. How can I assign to all of those 100 elements a single string for example:

```
string[] MyStr = new string[100]

//some code that assigns different words to all elements

string AssignToAll = "Something";
MyStr[1] = AssignToAll;
MyStr[2] = AssignToAll;
MyStr[3] = AssignToAll;
...
MyStr[100] = AssignToAll;
```

Is there any other method **except loops** to assign *"AssignToAll"* string to all of those 100 elements in *"MyStr"* string? - **C# Visual Studio**

Comment: It would be nice if you told us which language this is? Is it C#?

Comment: C#, sorry, always forgettin about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to use loops.
Use the for statement o the foreach, an example:

```
for(int pos=0;pos<MyStr.Lenght;pos++){
   MyStr[pos] = AssignToAll;
}
```